# Referencing collection variable inside underscore template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I pass `collection.toJSON()` as an argument to `underscore` template.

```
render: function() {
    this.template(this.collection.toJSON());
}
```

Inside the application router it gets initialized like that:

```
var productsList, products = new Products();
var p = products.fetch({ type: 'POST' });
p.done(function() {
    productsList = new ProductsList({ collection: products });
    productsList.render();
});
```

Then how do I reference the collection inside the template?

```
<% _.each(collection, function(p) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= p.price %></td>        
    </tr>
<% }); %>
```

When I tried it with both `products/collection` variables exceptions were raised saying that I used an unknown identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change render() function.

```
render: function() { 
    this.template({
        collection: this.collection.toJSON()
    });
}
```

Comment: I used {products: this.collection.toJSON()} ;)